# MYSQL Order By 2 rows depending on 2 other rows IDS

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a query that allows me to select the data like shown below
organizing by the role 45 and showing its win rate in order of DESC.
For example champ_1 = 45 and champ_2 = 36 but some time its can be champ_1 = 36 and champ_2 = 45. When like this how would i make the query so that is orders the win rate for champion 45 depending on if its champ1 or champ2 and then organizing it desc.

```
id      Role      Champ_1       Champ_2    Champ_1_winrate  Champ_2_winrate
---|------------|------------|-----------|-----------------|---------------
1  | 1          |     45     |     17    |       0.54      |      0.46      
2  | 1          |     67     |     45    |       0.52      |      0.48      
5  | 1          |     45     |     27    |       0.59      |      0.41     
3  | 1          |     45     |     35    |       0.29      |      0.71     
4  | 1          |     45     |     23    |       0.094     |      0.916     
6  | 1          |     80     |     45    |       0.38      |      0.62     
7  | 1          |     45     |     47    |       0.544     |      0.456     
8  | 1          |     32     |     45    |       0.78      |      0.22
```

It should show the data:

```
id      Role      Champ_1       Champ_2       winrate   
---|------------|------------|-----------|-----------------|
6  | 1          |     80     |     45    |       0.62      |      
5  | 1          |     45     |     27    |       0.59      |       
7  | 1          |     45     |     47    |       0.544     |     
1  | 1          |     45     |     17    |       0.54      |            
2  | 1          |     67     |     45    |       0.48      |            
3  | 1          |     45     |     35    |       0.29      |                   
8  | 1          |     32     |     45    |       0.22      |      
4  | 1          |     45     |     23    |       0.094     |
```

I have tried the following code and its the closest I have came for over 3 hours now, so could someone help please.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bronze_Matchups a 
WHERE (Champ_2 = 24 AND Role = 'JUNGLE') 
OR (Champ_1 = 24 AND Role = 'JUNGLE') 
ORDER BY Champ_2_winrate desc, Champ_1_winrate asc
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a case-statement in your order-by

```
SELECT * 
FROM Bronze_Matchups a 
WHERE 
   (Champ_2 = 24 AND Role = 'JUNGLE') 
   OR (Champ_1 = 24 AND Role = 'JUNGLE') 
ORDER BY 
   CASE
       WHEN Champ_2 = 24 THEN Champ_2_winrate
       ELSE Champ_1_winrate
   END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION and ORDER BY (add desc or asc in ORDER BY clause as you need)

```
SELECT a.id, a.Role, a.Champ_1, a.Champ_2, a.Champ_2_winrate as winrate
 FROM Bronze_Matchups a 
 WHERE a.Champ_2 = 24 
 AND a.Role = 'JUNGLE'
UNION
SELECT a.id, a.Role, a.Champ_1, a.Champ_2, a.Champ_1_winrate as winrate
 FROM Bronze_Matchups a 
 WHERE a.Champ_1 = 24
 AND a.Role = 'JUNGLE'
ORDER BY winrate
```